# How to catch all functions calls with reference by preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to scan all my script files in php by preg_match() in php.

I want to catch every lines, where is the function with one or more reference, but only calls, not definitions.

I mean I want to catch `foo(&$bar)`, but I want not to catch `function foo(&$bar)`, `foo($bar)`.

How to make negation of catching quotes in regexp?

Input:

```
function foo($bar) //line1
function foo(&$bar) //line2
foo($bar)  //line3
foo(&$bar) //line4
foo("&ampBar") //line5
```

Desired output:

```
foo(&$bar) //line4
```

Comment: You should post some input and attempts and expected output

Comment: It's impossible to do accurately with a regex. A regex cannot possibly find all possible permutations of `/* foo(&$bar) */` and similar false positives and exclude them. Use a parser.

Comment: @vks: It is not final answer yet, but it could be a good first step, thanks ;)

Comment: @vks: `(?<!function)\s+\w+\([^)]*&[^)]*\)` I patched a little. Please, write the answer and I will accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?<!function\s)\s*\w+\([^)]*&[^)]*\)$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/15

Comment: This solution assumes there is exactly one space between `function` and function name in the function definition.

Comment: I discovered another one problem: I want not to catch `foo("bar&ampBar")`

Comment: @user3383675 it does not catch that.See demo

Comment: @user3383675: It's your fault for not specifying all the cases.

Comment: @user3383675 what character can there be posiible before `&`.if we can narrow it down,it is an easy fix :)

Comment: @vks: Just drop the `(?<!function\s)`. It becomes meaningless when you anchor `^`.

Comment: If an assumption doesn't greatly affect the expected result, you can live with the assumption and state it clearly in your answer. Fixing your regex may make your regex matches some new cases (not stated in the question but valid), while makes it fails some other cases (not stated in the question but valid) which it previously could handle.

Comment: `(?<!function)\s{0,}\([^)]*&(?!amp)[^)]*\)` I think this could be a final version